# BootStrap and CSS - Sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I have a problem with [this sidebar](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/vertical-affix-menu-css-only).

I've copied the HTML of the sidebar and the CSS except for the part about html and body (because in my CSS I've already a style for them) and the problem is that I'm not able to make this sidebar tall as I wish! I'd like to make it as tall as the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved: i give an height:100% to all the parents of the row and added the class affix-content to the right column.

Another solution would be to add an offset to the column, but I think it's more a workaround than a real solution.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

```
.sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Why height:100%;  here ?

Comment: You would want to use the selector that is actually being used for your sidebar class instead of .sidebar of course but 100% height should tell the sidebar that you want it to take up the entire height of the screen.

Comment: @tlindell your solution seems to work but it'n not totally correct. In fact, now the sidebar is as tall as I want, but now the column next to it overlaps the sidebar! how can I solve this? I tried by adding the offset class, it's a good solution?

Comment: I would have to see the code and working example to understand the issue completely. did the offset work?